# Spotify Token Swap ruby file hosting

Tags: python, ios, ruby, spotify

I am trying to test the new Spotify iOS SDK on a device, and this requires setting up a spotify_token_swap ruby file for oauth authentication.

I've never used ruby before and am a bit lost.

I also tried a python version of this file but also can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any advice on ruby script hosting, or any experience on working with the Spotify iOS SDK that could help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this python service instead:

1. Download Google App engine [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction)
2. Install the launcher
3. Go to [chrismlarson's spotify-token-swap-gae](https://github.com/chrismlarson/spotify-token-swap-gae) and download the project, it will have everything you need.
4. In Google app engine launcher, Press add excisting project
5. Go Google app engines website and create a project, here you will get an app-id
6. in app.yaml , replace spotifyauth with the app-id
7. Press deploy
8. Done, you can now access it on the web at app-id.appspot.com/swap

Before I got this solution, I've spend hours in the jungle of Python and Ruby, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's another good alternative which you can deploy on Heroku:

https://github.com/bitstatic/spotify-swap-service-postgres

Just be mindful that you have to:

- Probably edit `config/environments.rb` and change `/mydb` to `/development`
- Run `rake db:create`
- Run `rake db:create_migration NAME=user_tokens`
- Edit `db/migration/{dateandtime}_user_tokens.rb` and replace it with:

  ```
  class UserTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
      create_table :user_tokens do |t|
          t.string :username
          t.string :refresh_token
      end
    end

    def down
      drop_table :user_tokens
    end
  end
  ```
- Run `rake db:migrate`

Most of this is covered in the Readme, and it even includes a helpful guide on setting up Postgres on your localhost! Once the migrations are set up it's a simple `git push heroku master`.

Good luck!

ps. Let Spotify know that setting up a token swap server is a lot of work, and they can follow Facebook's example of having 60-day tokens, by commenting on this issue: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/159